# How to add multiple buttons on a single AlertDialog

Tags: android

I have a butoon, on clicking of this button i want to open multiple buttons on a single AlertDialog like this :[image]

Give Me a help :

I was using this.... to add multiple buttons

```
alertDialog.setButton(delete, "Delete", new OnClickListener() {
        
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
    });
```

but I found..., change setButton() to setButton2().. something like..... wt xcan i do for this....

Comment: Make s Custom Dialog and inflated layout xml file to `setVIew()` it. Now add buttons as many as you want.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would inflate the AlertDialog with my own custom view (my_alert_dialog.xml).

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
//inflate view for alertdialog since we are using multiple views inside a viewgroup (root = Layout top-level) (linear, relative, framelayout etc..)
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_alert_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root)); 

Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1); // etc.. for button2,3,4.
alert.setView(view);
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 144):

A simple solution **without xml**:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Title");
builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]
        {"button 1", "button 2", "button 3", "button 4"},
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                // of the selected item
                switch (which) {
                    case 0:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "clicked 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "clicked 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "clicked 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "clicked 4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
builder.create().show();
```

Comment: This worked for me! However this gives you a vertical list rather than a horizontal.

Comment: But how to add the message for the dialog content?

Comment: @teapeng : builder.setMessage() overrides the buttons, so I guess you're left with just builder.setTitle()

Comment: best ever, way to go!

Comment: It crashes on builder.create().show();

Comment: i got crash Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0, that's really bad answer

Answer (score 3):

You can only create a Alertdialog with 3 buttons if you dont make the view by yourself.

You can either make your own custom view in xml.

but i'd suggest you just make a List.

Check
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog
"Adding a list"

Answer (score 0):

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
RelativeLayout featureLayout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.yourview, null);
dialog.setContentView(featureLayout);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int item = 0;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
list.add("D"); 
item = -1; 

 for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { 
    item++; 
    intList.add(i); 
  }

showRatingBarAlertDialog(intList);

private void showRatingBarAlertDialog(ArrayList<Integer> Id) {
    if (item != -1) {
        RatingFragment alertDialog = RatingFragment.instance(BaseActivity.this, Id.get(item), (ratingValue, comments) -> {
            CXLog.d(TAG, "select the rating::" + ratingValue);
            CXLog.d(TAG, "comment the feednback  " + comments);
            item--;
            showRatingBarAlertDialog(requestId);
        });
        alertDialog.show(CXBaseActivity.this.getFragmentManager(), "alertDialog");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I add any number of buttons (Kotlin code).
In this example I add a button `My Button`.

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
val dialog = builder.create()
dialog.setOnShowListener {
        val anyButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
        class MyButton : MaterialButton (this, null, android.R.attr.buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle)
        val parentView = anyButton.parent as? ViewGroup
        val myButton = MyButton()
        myButton.text = "My Button"
        parentView?.addView(myButton)
}
dialog.show()
```