# How to add multiple button in alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How to add a third button in alert dialog? I'm using an alert dialog in my code but I want to show multiple button in the dialog.

```
alertDialogBuilder
   .setMessage("Click yes to search on google")
   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
   {
      public void onClick(
          DialogInterface dialog,
          int id) {
          // if this button is clicked, close current activity
          searchFor = contents;
          Intent viewSearch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
          viewSearch.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, searchFor);
          startActivity(viewSearch);
      }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
   {
     public void onClick(
          DialogInterface dialog,
          int id)
       {
         finish();
       }
   });
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: There is also a neutra button, you can set it in the same as you set negative and positive buttons

Comment: yup..setNeutralButton() is what you want..

Answer (score 3):

First of all there is [setNeutralButton()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setNeutralButton(int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)) method. This is the simplies one. The secodn one can be inflating extra XML view and then you can add as many buttons as you want.

Also I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19658646/1080517), which seems quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can have only 3 buttons max if you use the default style

use a custom `View` and do `AlertDialog.Builder.setView(mycustomview);`