# How to imitate the layout of Android AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, user-interface

The `AlertDialog` in Android's API provides an easy way to produce nicely looking `Dialog` with either one, two or three buttons. By "nicely looking", I meant the buttons are laid out nicely of equal width at the bottom and they do not have borders and grey backgrounds as the usual `Button` object. This is a little bit limited in some situation, in fact, I am in need of 4 buttons.

I want to ask if there is a way to produce the same user interface. Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671428/how-can-i-add-a-third-button-to-an-android-alert-dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a class extending the alertdialog, then put as many buttons as you want. But im fairly sure that a custom alertdialog has to have it's view inflated with a layout inflator instead of simply using setcontentView

Comment: Thanks. I forgot the power of GridLayout which allows us to organize things homogeneously.

Comment: If having them evenly spaced was the issue, there's no reason you couldn't do it with a relative layout or linear layout utilizing layout weights.